# How to determine the speed of GLUT1 transporter using Michaelis-Menten kinetics?

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics, enzymes

I am reviewing a passage in my Lehninger Biochemistry Textbook (6th Edition), and the following passage has me very confused.

How can one sentence from this passage claim that when [S]<sub>out</sub> = K<sub>t</sub>, the rate of uptake is 1/2 V<sub>max</sub>, but then go on to say that when the concentration in the blood is *close* to K<sub>t</sub> that GLUT1 operates near V<sub>max</sub>?

[image]